# Typescript: Type 'string' is not assignable to custom type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings, typescript2.0, styled-components

I have a type like this,

```
interface StyleProps {
  display?: 'hide' | 'active'
}
```

and the type is being used by component below

```
<Section display={`${this.state.section !== 'chatbot' ? 'hide' : 'active'}`}>
```

`display` can only be `hide` or `active` but I'm still getting this error

```
 TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"hide" | "active" | undefined'.
```

Is there any way to see what's in `display` or anything im doing it wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get rid of this error if you remove the template literal and just pass in either `'hide'` or `'active'` directly.

```
<Section display={this.state.section !== 'chatbot' ? 'hide' : 'active'}>
```